insert on duplicate key update deadlock
mysql version: 5.7
Suppose I have a table like this:
create table test  
(`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`unique_key` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`count` int(11) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_key` (`unique_key`))  

And concurrent INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements are executed based on the 'unique_key' to insert new records or update the 'count'.
According to some, deadlocks in INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occur on gap locks. And gap locks are used to prevent phantom reads in the REPEATABLE READ isolation level.
If I take the following approaches, can I completely avoid deadlocks in concurrent scenarios?

Set the transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED. In this case, there's no need to address phantom reads, and therefore no gap locks.
Enable autocommit, executing only one INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement at a time.
Distribute the execution based on unique_key so that concurrent operations don't handle the same unique_key.

If there is still a probability (even very low) of a deadlock, could anyone give an example?

Guys, what I'm really curious about is whether the deadlock in INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE still exists after implementing the three measures mentioned above.
Of course, from a purely theoretical standpoint, let's assume a scenario where only concurrent INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operations are involved, without considering other potential operations on the table in real-world scenarios.
I've just conducted a test, and I have learned more about this statement "Set the transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED. In this case, there's no need to address phantom reads, and therefore no gap locks".
Here's my test setup:
MySQL version: 5.7.44-log
Isolation level: RC

Create a table

    CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `unique_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_key` (`unique_key`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;


Insert one record

    INSERT INTO test (unique_key,count) VALUES(1, 1)


Start transaction 1

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test (`unique_key`, `count`)
VALUES(1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;


Start transaction 2

START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM test;


Check INNODB STATUS

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

The purpose of this test is to make transaction 2 wait for transaction 1, giving me enough time to examine the locks held by transaction 1 in INNODB STATUS.
The key finding is that transaction 1 (with transaction ID 3142) holds 3 locks. As below.
---TRANSACTION 3142, ACTIVE 18 sec
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 8, OS thread handle 33432, query id 571 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
TABLE LOCK table `ifly_ads_statis`.`test` trx id 3142 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 46 page no 4 n bits 72 index idx_unique_key of table `ifly_ads_statis`.`test` trx id 3142 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;

RECORD LOCKS space id 46 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `ifly_ads_statis`.`test` trx id 3142 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000c46; asc      F;;
 2: len 7; hex 2f0000014a0541; asc /   J A;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;

Notably, there's a lock: index idx_unique_key of table 'ifly_ads_statis'.'test' trx id 3142 lock_mode X. `According to some, this is a next-key lock.
So, at the RC level, a next-key lock appears. A next-key lock is a combination of a gap lock and a record lock, providing even stronger locking than a gap lock alone.
Does this test result correctly indicate that "next-key locks can occur at the RC level"?
When I stated "Set the transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED. In this case, there's no need to address phantom reads, and therefore no gap locks.", what I really had in mind was, "...and therefore no gap locks and next-key locks."
If "next-key locks can occur at the RC level", then this makes it easier for me to understand why INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE might still deadlock, even after implementing the three measures mentioned above.
But yet another question, it's widely claimed online that next-key locks are designed to address phantom reads, but RC isolation level doesn't have to worry about phantom reads.
Why can we still observe next-key locks under RC?
Does this have anything to do with MySQL versions?

Yrying to avoid deadlocks is absolutely the wrong approach! Prepare your code to handle deadlocks and you will be fine! By all means, try to minimise the chances of deadlocks happening, but consider them as a way of resolving certain conflicts in database operations!

If phantom reads can be avoided at the business level, it is highly recommended to use the Read Committed (RC) isolation level. It not only enables you to avoid deadlock situations, but also can improve performance in high-concurrency scenarios.
In addition, even if you use the Repeatable Read (RR) isolation level, deadlocks are not very likely to occur, unless you operate multiple statements in a single transaction and do not release the locks on multiple records in a timely manner. The deadlock scenarios are as follows:
Transaction 1：

begin;

select * from sbtest3 where id = 120 for update;



Transacation 2：

begin;

select * from sbtest3 where id = 121 for update;



transaction 1：

select * from sbtest3 where id = 121 for update;

wait for transaction 2 to relase the lock on the id=121


transaction 2：

select * from sbtest3 where id = 120 for update;

wait for transaction 1 to release the lock on the id=120


In your scenario, suppose there is the following data:
1 10 1
2 11 1
3 13 1
4 14 1

transaction 1:

insert 12, will lock 11,13


transaction 2:

update 13, will lock 13


It won't cause a deadlock.
To sum up, as long as you use the Read Committed (RC) isolation level, and each transaction operates only a single statement and commits it immediately, generally, deadlocks are not very likely to occur.

You cannot avoid deadlocks under any isolation levels if you have concurrent users modifying the same data. You can minimise the chances of them occuring, but cannot eliminate it.
